# Correct permissions for a cache directory

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, aws

I have setup a [PhalconPHP](https://phalconphp.com/en/) project on an AWS EC2 instance. To get thinks working I gave the cache directory `777` permissions. I realise this is bad practice - what would be the correct permissions for a cache directory on a webserver?

I presume it must specific to the user the `httpd` service is running as (the output from the method given by the top voted answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as) implies that the user is `apache`). But I obviously want to keep my `ec2-user` having write access to the directory (I don't want to have to use `sudo` the whole time).

What would be the correct set of permissions for the directory? I have a `www` group that `ec2-user` is part of, should `apache` be added to that?

Comment: Do 700 for everything and do an ACL for the other user. There's no sense in giving an entire group access to just give access to one other user.